# Cannot bind pvc with efs static pv in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-efs

I'm trying to bind a persistent volume using efs.

I have a kubernetes cluster based on ec2 instances and a static efs volume accessible from k8s cluster subnet (security groups opens).

I firstly create an efs unencrypted volume then in my kubernetes cluster I use this chart to access it :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: "test"
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: "500Gi"
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: aws-efs
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: "fs-01b79fe9a42a2d166"
```

When I apply this the pv appear on the list :

```
test            500Gi      RWX            Retain           Available                                   aws-efs                 5m12s
```

First problem :

- When I change the volumeHandle value and try something that doesn't exist the volume is still created. So is there any way to check that this volume is well bind to my efs ?

After that I try to declare a pvc :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
  name: test
  namespace: prometheus
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: aws-efs
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: test
```

But here I'm facing an issue :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                   From                                                                           Message
  ----     ------                ----                  ----                                                                           -------
  Normal   Provisioning          9m9s                  efs.csi.aws.com_cluster-k8s-mgr-01_babd61df-c93b-448f-8169 External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "prometheus/test"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed    9m9s                  efs.csi.aws.com_cluster-k8s-mgr-01_babd61df-c93b-448f-8169 failed to provision volume with StorageClass "aws-efs": rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = Missing provisioningMode parameter
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  3m1s (x26 over 9m9s)  persistentvolume-controller                                                    waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "efs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
```

I also tried dynamic provisionning :

- I created a storageclass :

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-04d246c34ff38f892
  directoryPerms: "700"
```

Then a pvc :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

But this time I got a new error when checking pvc description:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age    From                                                                           Message
  ----     ------              ----   ----                                                                           -------
  Normal   Provisioning        6m55s  efs.csi.aws.com_cluster-k8s-mgr-01_babd61df-c93b-448f-8169 External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/efs-claim"
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  6m55s  efs.csi.aws.com_cluster-k8s-mgr-01_babd61df-c93b-448f-8169 failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Failed to fetch File System info: describe File System failed: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
           For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
  Normal   ExternalProvisioning  52s (x26 over 6m55s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "efs.csi.aws.com" or manually created by system administrator
```

I recently did an upgrade on this cluster :

- k8s 1.18 -> 1.21
- efs driver 0.3 -> 1.2.1

Maybe the problem comes from here ?

Some static efs volumes are currently well bind on this cluster using first method and same network policies.

I spend a lot of time making tests but I still don't know where the issue comes from...

PS : That's my first thread, don't hesitate to tell me if I did something wrong :p

Answer (score 0):

You're using the CSI plugin for EFS based PVs. This means that the 'validation' part is to be handled by the `efs-csi` driver (AWS API) and not by the Kubernetes API. Therefore, you can expect that *any* value of `volumeHandle` to end up creating a PV successfully. It is not until you will *attempt to use that PV*,  that you will start facing problems. So, there is no way to ensure the `volumeHandle` is valid from the Kubernetes API.

> Tip: In static PVCs, if you are already specifying `storageClassName` there is no need to put the `storage-provisioner` annotation. See [this k8s doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class).

### Static Provisioning Error

The error simply means you did not specify the `provisioningMode` on the storage class object `aws-efs`. Adding that should fix the problem.

### Dynamic Provisioning Error

The error with dynamic provisioning simply means that IAM flow is somehow not correctly configured. You can use the `efs-csi` documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html) to ensure the IAM setup is correct.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great explanation, I had multiple miss understanding. Thanks !